# ¿Cuándo no existen productos agregados al carro de la compra generan algunos errores, como puedo corregirlos?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Cuando se agregan productos al carro de la compra dichos errores desaparecen no se muestran parece no ser graves ya que todo fluye con normalidad que incluso los podría desactivar realizando lo siguiente: `error_reporting(0);` pero por otra parte no me parece que esta sea lo más útil un código no debe generar ni más mínimo error.

Volviendo al tema cuando no existen productos añadidos al carro, me genera dos errores, que son lo siguiente:

> Warning: str_repeat(): Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0 in `$strMarcas  = str_repeat('?,', count($inputItems) - 1) . '?';`

> Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in `$stmt->bind_param($strTipos, ...$inputItems);`

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $items = (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['cart'])) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array();
    foreach($items as $id_product => $item) {
        foreach($item  as $color => $sizes) {
            foreach($sizes as $size => $quantity) {
                $meQty += $quantity;
            }
        }
    }
    $inputItems = array_keys($items);
    $strMarcas  = str_repeat('?,', count($inputItems) - 1) . '?';
    $strTipos = str_repeat('i', count($inputItems));

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_product, type_product, cover_product, title_product, subtitle_product, price_old, price FROM tbl_products WHERE id_product in ($strMarcas)");
    $stmt->bind_param($strTipos, ...$inputItems);
    $stmt->execute();
```

¿Cómo puedo evitar que se generen esos errores, cuando no se agregan productos al carro de la compra?

Comment: Creo que simplemente necesitas chequear si el `count` de `$inputItems` es mas grande que 0

Comment: @alanfcm como tendría que quedar amigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo tu codigo depende de el numero de `$items` en el carrito, si no hay nada simplemente no ejecutas el codigo.  Puedes hacer un chequeo asi:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $items = (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['cart'])) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array();
    if (count($items) > 0) {
      foreach($items as $id_product => $item) {
        foreach($item  as $color => $sizes) {
            foreach($sizes as $size => $quantity) {
                $meQty += $quantity;
            }
        }
      }
      $inputItems = array_keys($items);
      $strMarcas  = str_repeat('?,', count($inputItems) - 1) . '?';
      $strTipos = str_repeat('i', count($inputItems));

      $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_product, type_product, cover_product, title_product, subtitle_product, price_old, price FROM tbl_products WHERE id_product in ($strMarcas)");
      $stmt->bind_param($strTipos, ...$inputItems);
      $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Tocará realizarlo de esa manera, lo tenía en mente pero pensé que podría ser solucionado desde la linea que señalaba el error, gracias.

Comment: Si se puede, pero de esta forma es mas eficiente.